# Как преобразовать string в обычный массив с элементами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Это игра в пятнашки, мне автоматически генерируется произвольная доска, но проблема в том, что это строка.
Например, сгенерировалась эта строка

```
------------------
[' 3', ' 8', ' 1']
[' 7', '  ', ' 5']
[' 6', ' 4', ' 2']
------------------
```

Хотел бы это преобразовать в одномерный массив.
Например в это,

```
[' 3', ' 8', ' 1',' 7', '  ', ' 5',' 6', ' 4', ' 2']
```

чтобы потом мог обращаться к каждому элементу массива.

Вот как генерируется эта доска

```
def __str__(self):
    symbols = [tile_to_string(x) for x in self.__tiles]
    msg = '-'*self.__size*6+'\n'
    for row in range(self.__size):
        msg +=str(symbols[row*self.__size:row*self.__size+self.__size])
        msg += '\n'
    msg += '-'*self.__size*6
    return msg
```

Comment: где у вас строка? как она у вас сгенерировалась? я вижу три списка, например.

Comment: сейчас отредактиую, чтобы понятно было

Comment: Всё равно ничего непонятно. «Это» это кто? «мне автоматически генерируется» — кем и где генерируется? Почему «это» генерирует именно строку, а не какой-то более удобный тип данных?

Comment: А зачем эта доска генерируется внутри `__str__`? Что мешает сделать нормальный метод, который сразу будет генерировать нормальный одномерный массив без всяких костылей со строками?

Comment: так это не я делаю, я должен только это использовать и написать код, который проверяет, есть ли решение при таком положении костяшек

Comment: А вы не пробовали у этого «не я» спросить более адекватный способ чтения доски, нежели извращения со строками? Например, беглый поиск по гитхабу подсказывает, что иногда существует метод `read_tile`, через который можно было бы легко и просто собрать одномерный массив

Comment: все, спасибо, разобрался, даже не подумал бы, что существует такой метод

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/pdSXXV

```
import re

str = """------------------
[' 3', ' 8', ' 1'][' 7', '  ', ' 5'][' 6', ' 4', ' 2']
------------------"""

print(re.findall(r"(?<=')\s*\d*(?=')", str))
```

```
[' 3', ' 8', ' 1', ' 7', '  ', ' 5', ' 6', ' 4', ' 2']
```